# How can I select the newest row and the row closest to 24 hours ago in one select statement?

Tags: mysql

I currently have two select statements to get the newest row and the row closest to 24 hours ago. What is the most optimized method to select both in one statement?

I am currently retrieving the newest with:

```
SELECT `Price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` ORDER BY `ts` DESC LIMIT 1
```

And the one closest to 24 hours ago with:

```
SELECT `Price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` WHERE `ts` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY `ts` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: For a non-trivial amount of rows your approach is the fastest (that I can think of). The only improvement would be a UNION, but that's still 2 queries

Comment: i doubt that you want them in the same column, so see SELECT MIN, MAX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have just to merge the results, you can use the `union` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

```
(SELECT `Price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` ORDER BY `ts` DESC LIMIT 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT `Price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` WHERE `ts` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY `ts` ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that would be it but I thought there might be a better method.. I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Your asking about a union

```
SELECT `Price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` ORDER BY `ts` DESC LIMIT 1
union 
SELECT `Price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` WHERE `ts` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY `ts` ASC LIMIT 1
```